# How do I change the REST context generated by enunciate?

Tags: java, resteasy, enunciate

I have the following annotation in my RESTEasy code:

```
@Path("/v1/authenticateService")
```

Enunciate generates a "Mount Point" in the documentation as:

```
/rest/v1/authenticateService/authenticate
```

I have tried using the following in my enunciate.xml, to override the "/rest" context:

```
<services>
    <rest defaultRestSubcontext="/gateway-service-access-pox" />
</services>
```

I have also tried the following, but it didn't do anything, either:

```
<deployment protocol="https" host="(host)" context="/gateway-service-access-pox" />
```

I am using enunciate 1.23 to generate docs for a Maven 3, multi-module project.

Here is what is written to the console:

```
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-cli) @ gateway-service-access-pox ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.4
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.23
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.4
[INFO] Generating "Web Service API" report    --- maven-enunciate-plugin:1.23
[INFO] initializing enunciate.
[INFO] invoking enunciate:generate step...
[INFO] invoking enunciate:compile step...
[INFO] invoking enunciate:build step...
[INFO] closing enunciate.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

More info...
The complete enunciate.xml (in case there is a problem affecting the entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enunciate label="platform-gateway-api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.23.xsd">

<api-import pattern="com.intuit.platform.gateway.common.DetailedResponse" />
<api-import pattern="com.intuit.platform.gateway.service.access.domain.*" />
<api-import pattern="com.intuit.platform.gateway.service.identity.domain.Identity" />

<deployment protocol="https" host="(host)" context="/gateway-service-access-pox" />

<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/integration/detailedResponse/v1" id="common" />
    <namespace uri="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/identity/user/v1" id="user" />
    <namespace uri="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/access/token/v1" id="token" />
</namespaces>

<services>
    <rest defaultRestSubcontext="/gateway-service-access-pox" />
</services>

<modules>
    <!-- Docs -->
    <docs splashPackage="com.intuit.platform.gateway.service.ticket.api" title="Platform Gateway Access API"
        copyright="Intuit Inc">
        <download name="License" file="LICENSE.txt" description="The license file governing the use of this API." />
    </docs>
    <!-- Disable all the client generation tools -->
    <basic-app disabled="true" />
    <c disabled="true" />
    <csharp disabled="true" />
    <java-client disabled="true" />
    <jaxws-client disabled="true" />
    <jaxws-ri disabled="true" />
    <jaxws-support disabled="true" />
    <jersey disabled="true" />
    <obj-c disabled="true" />
    <xml disabled="true" />
</modules>
</enunciate>
```

BTW, if there is better way to get help on this issue (some sort of bug forum), please let me know. I am a newbie with enunciate and didn't know if this was a bug or my ignorance.

Comment: Is it perhaps this issue? https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/issues/14
However, it works for me. Also I can't see _docsDir_ attribute set in your <docs /> element - if you do not have generated doc in the root, you need to tell where do you plan to put them, so Enunciate generates correct relative path to your API.

Answer (score 2):

as Ryan said the "defaultRestSubcontext" works. For example I used it this way to remove "rest" from default generated mount point:

<services>
     <rest defaultRestSubcontext="/" />
</services>

If one set defaultRestSubcontext to "/" the generation starts from "/" and then followed by the endpoint's path.

P.S. I am using Enunciate 1.24

Answer (score 1):

Well... I have being around this for couple days and finally it is working and the mount point has proper default rest subcontext :)

2 Things I did to make it work.

1. enable the XML module

   ```
   <xml disabled="false" />
   ```
2. Add enunciate-xml jar to runtime.

I don't know why is that, but it is working for me now.